# Different color for Types/methods in syntax highlighting in Eclipse for Scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, themes, syntax-highlighting, scala-ide

Is anyone able to use Scala IDE in Eclipse with syntax highlighting showing different colors for types and methods definition? For me, variables/values, method definitions and class names are all same color no matter what.

I would really like something close to Scala highlighting in Sublime Text 2. I've tried the equivalent eclipse color theme for it but the colors get terrible with Scala source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felipe, are you using the [Scala IDE Helium nightly](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html)? Semantic Highlighting is not available in the 2.0 release, you need to use one of the Helium nightlies.

The website is not up to date (it says Semantic Highlighting is coming soon, while it is already in), I'll update that page today.

Also, the [scala-ide-user Mailing List](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user) is usually a better place for general questions about features in the Scala IDE.

Comment: I saw that "coming soon" and thought it would take a while to arrive! thanks!